# Using jQuery read more with iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using [this](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) but in some browsers I cannot get the iframe to display so I've added a function for it to be refreshed which works great.

The only problem is that this refreshes all iframe instead of just the one in the div being expanded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.box').readmore({
    speed: 500,
    collapsedHeight:112,
    embedCSS: false,
    moreLink: '<a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>',
    lessLink: '<a href="#" class="btn">Read Less</a>',
    afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
      if( expanded) { 
        $( 'iframe' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

I know I could just put a class or an id on the iframe itself but this is not an option in my situation.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to make your jQuery selector more specific to the iframe you want to select. `$('iframe')` in jQuery means "select all iframe tags on the page". If I had more information or context, I may be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: $(this).find('iframe').attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'iframe' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
```

use 'this' keyword